# Lagrange method

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I can't transform quadratic form to canonical using Lagrange method. $x_1^2 + 5x_2^2 - 4x_3^2 + 2x_1x_2 - 4x_1x_3$. I tried to solve it, but stopped at this moment: $x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + 4x_2^2 - 4x_3^2- 4x_1x_3 = (x_1+x_2)^2 + 4x_2^2 - 4x_3^2- 4x_1x_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you want to get all occurrences of $x_1$ into the first bracket. So you start with
$$x_1^2+5x_2^2+4x_2^2-4x_3^2+2x_1x_2-4x_1x_3=(x_1+x_2-2x_3)^2+4x_2^2+4x_2x_3-8x_3^2.$$

Can you continue from there?

Comment: $(x_1+x_2-2x_3)^2+4(x_2+1/2x_3)^2-9x_3^2$

Comment: Seems ok to me. You can also rewrite $9x_3^2=(3x_3)^2$ and $4(x_2+1/2x_3)^2=(2x_2+x_3)^2$, if you want the coefficients to be $\pm1$'s (or zeroes). You can even check the result online - for example, [in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(a%2Bb-2c)%5E2%2B4(b%2Bc%2F2)%5E2-(3c)%5E2).

Answer (score 1):

The order you get to first with Lagrange's method is

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

or
$$ (x+y-2z)^2 + 4 (y + \frac{1}{2}z)^2 - 9 z^2 $$
the same as

$$ (x+y-2z)^2 +  (2y + z)^2 - 9 z^2 $$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 4 & 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 &  - 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$